# How to parse annotations from EdmEntitySet using Olingo Java client / ODATA 4

Tags: java, odata, olingo

Suppose I have below entity set defined in odata service

```
<EntitySet Name="Photos" EntityType="Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin.Photo">
<Annotation Term="Org.OData.Core.V1.ResourcePath" String="Photos"/>
<Annotation Term="Org.OData.Capabilities.V1.SearchRestrictions">
<Record>
<PropertyValue Property="Searchable" Bool="true"/>
<PropertyValue Property="UnsupportedExpressions">
<EnumMember>Org.OData.Capabilities.V1.SearchExpressions/none</EnumMember>
</PropertyValue>
</Record>
</Annotation>
<Annotation Term="Org.OData.Capabilities.V1.InsertRestrictions">...</Annotation>
</EntitySet>
```

I am able to get this entity from the entity container but I also want to capture the annotations defined with it.
For example in this case I want to know what are various SearchRestrictions on this entity set.

Once we get the annotations by using entitySet.getAnnotations() we are not able to get further information from the annotation like term,qualifier, property etc because all their getters are returning null.
I am facing the exact issue mentioned in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-983 but my usecase is slightly different, so I am unable to use this fix correctly and need help.

This is how I am reading the metadata from the Url with authentication

```
EdmMetadataRequest request = client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getMetadataRequest(serviceUrl);
ODataRetrieveResponse<Edm> response = (ODataRetrieveResponse<Edm>) OdataRequestUtil.executeRequest(request, authDetails); 
//execute Request method just set authentication headers and then call request.execute()
edm = response.getBody();
```

Comment: Which client library are you using. Olingo Java or JavaScript client or any other client? Posting the sample code on how you are consuming the data will help.

Comment: @Shiva I am using Olingo Java client.Made the edit to make question more clear.Actually I am facing the exact issue mentioned in [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-983) which was fixed wrt to [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-1062)